# Redirecting stdin to a temporary file?

Tags: c, unix, io-redirection, temporary-files

I want stdin to be redirected to a string of text supplied in my program.  I want to write the string of text to a temporary file and then point stdin to that file.  I'm a little unsure about this code because it seems to blend low level function calls like `write()` and `dup()` with higher level function calls like `fclose()`.  Is this the correct approach?:

```
char* buffer = "This is some text";
int nBytes = strlen(buffer);
FILE* file = tmpfile();
int fd = fileno(file);
write(fd,buffer,nBytes);
rewind(file);
dup2(fd,0);
fclose(file);
```

**EDIT**

As per a suggestion in the comments, I tried approaching this problem with pipes.  If I want to use pipes, would this be the correct approach?  I still want feedback on the first approach as well:

```
int fd[2];
pipe(fd); // For sake of simplicity assume returns 0 (no error).
char* buffer = "This is some text";
int nBytes = strlen(buffer);
write(fd[1],buffer,nBytes);
close(fd[1]);
dup2(fd[0],0);
close(fd[0]);
```

Comment: To find it out, you will need to compile that code and execute it.

Comment: You already have your string in RAM, why would you copy it to a file and then read it back to RAM?

Comment: Because later I am going to run `execvp()` and I want this string to be read in by the command I invoke.

Comment: Just open a pipe and stuff your string to it.

Comment: If you cannot do a pipe for some reason, use `mkstemp` and sidestep stdio entirely.

Comment: Can you show how this example would work with `mkstemp`?  Alternatively, can you demonstrate how this example would work with pipes?  I'm not very familiar with them.

Comment: `mkstemp` just gives you an open file descriptor, sidestepping `FILE*` (use `man mkstemp` to read more). I cannot give a tutorial on pipes in this small box.

Comment: Are you sure you are not looking for [`freopen`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/freopen/) ? Also check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584868/rerouting-stdin-and-stdout-from-c

Comment: Would follow this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543443/in-c-how-do-you-redirect-stdin-stdout-stderr-to-files-when-making-an-execvp-or