# Reading gcc output in a string

Tags: c, windows, redirect, gcc, stdout

If we execute gcc to compile a source file through the `system()` function, how can I capture the gcc output in a string ?

---

I tried with `popen` which works as long as it reads something like `"PAUSE"`, but did not work with gcc as it runs a new child process.

Comment: Use pipe(2) and dup2(2) before fork/exec to redirect stdin/stdout.

Comment: What output are you talking about? The compiled file? The error messages?

Comment: @rici console output. Which is I think the error messages.

Comment: Windows equivalents of pipe/dup2 are DuplicateHandle and CreatePipe.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways.

Simple way:
Redirect the output to a temporary file and read the temporary file into a string.

You can use pipes. In the child process, redirect the output to pipe and read from the other end of the pipe into a string.
See `man pipe`

```
//In the parent process
int fd[2]
pipes(fd);

//Use fork+execv instead of system to launch child process.
if (fork()==0) {
    //Redirect output to fd[0]
   dup2(fileno(fd[0]), STDOUT_FILENO);
   dup2(fileno(fd[0]), STDERR_FILENO);
   //Use execv function to load gcc with arguments.

} else {
  //read from the other end fd[1]
}
```

See thread at http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1627614.html.

Also see [In C how do you redirect stdin/stdout/stderr to files when making an execvp() or similar call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543443/in-c-how-do-you-redirect-stdin-stdout-stderr-to-files-when-making-an-execvp-or)

For Windows, this link might help you. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
Flow is almost same as Linux. Syntax and primitives might be different. Here, idea is to use Pipe and redirect process output files to your pipe file.

Comment: Yes the simple way is pretty much what everyone thinks of in the very first moment. However, they realize that it might be simple, but certainly not the best way. On the other hand, this link's content looks quite complex. I suspected it will involve pid ids and stuff like that.

Comment: Especially complex, given the `windows` tag :-)

Comment: I don't like windows. But my project is stuck in windows which I believe.. is a common case for a number of people these days.

Comment: @DeltaProxy: See the edit. I hope this code layout might help you.

Comment: No problem. I still have solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to read the error messages produced by `gcc`, you need to remember that they are sent to `stderr`, not `stdout`. `popen` captures `stdout` but does not redirect `stderr`.

If `system` on Windows provides a standard posix shell, you could redirect `stderr` to `stdout` in the command line you provide to `popen`, by adding the redirection `2>&1`.

Comment: OH. Good remark. That makes sense and also makes it harder to be accomplished indeed.

Comment: @DeltaProxy: On Unix, it would be trivial; you'd just do `popen("gcc -o a.out file.c 2>&1", "r");` or something of that form. Maybe that will work in your environment.

Comment: It worked.. on a way. Partially. It redirected the symbol `^` as well as some space. But it must redirect the backslash for the directory of the source file, which means it will be read as an escape sequence and this follows to be a problem.

Comment: @DeltaProxy: Why would it be read as an escape? `fread` (or `fgets`) just reads the bytes which are in the file. (Except for end-of-line translation for non-binary files on Windows.)

Comment: @DeltaProxy: Also, if you have a surprisingly recent version of gcc, you should investigate the option `-fno-diagnostics-show-caret`

Comment: I am printing the output buffer with printf. `-fno-diagnostics-show-caret` couldn't be fount even in google.

Comment: @DeltaProxy: Don't do that. Or if you do that, use a format. Otherwise, you're in ready-to-be-pwned land

Comment: then how would I print them? (I am also using gtk and gtksourceview) Was hopefully expecting the way to be compatible with printing the result in a `GtkTextView`

Comment: @DeltaProxy: `printf("%s", buffer)` or `fputs(buffer, stdout)`  are two good ways. Never ever ever write `printf(buffer);`. Whenever you see that line, think "danger".

Comment: Oh, and why use google when the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Language-Independent-Options.html#index-fdiagnostics-show-caret-264) is online?

Comment: I am not a `gcc` master, unfortunately and I don't get what does `-fno-diagnostics-show-caret` has to do with the problem. (Not a native speaker as well). Yes I am using `g_print("[%s]", buffer);` which is the analogue of `printf`. But I am still receiving the output of `^` and spaces.

Comment: @DeltaProxy: Recent versions of gcc show you where the error occurred by outputting a line containing a single ^ which points at the error position (by having enough spaces before it so that it is in the right place.) That's easier for human beings than a column number. Programs which understand column numbers can avoid the ^ (which is called a caret, and not just in English) by telling gcc "don't use carets in diagnostics", i.e. `-fno-diagnostics-show-caret`. The caret pointers also don't work if you use a proportionally-spaced font instead of a fixed-space font.

Comment: The font of the console is monotype. Yes I receive the error in the console containing ^ at the line of the error. Adding this argument to the list of compiler arguments doesn't occur to change the the thing.

Comment: Screenshot after the invoking of `popen` to compile a file with the adding: http://screencast.com/t/4uFUUj6G It seem to redirect properly only the `^` ?

Comment: @DeltaProxy: You got me. Maybe the redirect doesn't work properly on Windows. Maybe there's a bug in your program. The fact that the ^ line seems to be written twice is suspicious, and needs some investigation. I'd start by writing a simple program which writes to stderr and see if you can get that to work. It wouldn't surprise me if it were a windows oddity, but I have zero windows experience so I can't offer much experience.

Comment: Would you start a chat room? You can offer much. I was never to system programming.