# separate shell command with some symbols

Tags: c++, linux, shell

I am implementing a shell by using C++ as my coding language.

Basically I define a `char *argv[128]` for storing the command by strtok the space.

So if I input `ls -a -l > test.txt` it will turn to

```
ls
-a
-l
>
test.txt
```

What I want to do is to separate the '>' symbol so I can continue implement the redirection and pipe function.

Well I want to define a vector to store the ls-a-l and test.txt and let the program do the redirection function.

How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "separate"? It's already separate in your list.

Comment: @Mat Well I want to define a vector to store the ls-a-l and test.txt and let the program do the redirection function.

Comment: You want `argv` to be of `std::vector<std::string>` type, not `char*argv[128]`. You are asking how to parse and tokenize a line. And you need lexical conventions (how would you input an argument containing a space)!

Comment: what do u mean by let the program do the redirection ?

Comment: Which program is going to do the redirection?  `ls` won't; it always writes to standard output.  It is up to your shell to make sure that the output of `ls` goes to the file you want it to go to rather than the terminal.  There's nothing to stop you, and probably some good, in revising the argument list so that I/O redirections are recognized and stored separately from actual command arguments.

Comment: Also, any fixed length argument list you're likely to devise is too short.  You need to be prepared to handle hundreds, even thousands, of arguments.

Comment: @ali786 I want the shell I built to do the redirection and pipe jobs.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well this is just a project of my course.. The max length of command is 256 so for now I just set the length as 128.

Comment: @HoweChen: you are wrong; the command `ls *` could expand to `/bin/ls` invoked with many thousands of arguments.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch You are right but this project limited the length to 256

Answer (score 0):

You should define lexical conventions for your shell. For instance in POSIX shells you can pass an argument with a space by e.g. quoting it or escaping it with a backslash, like in 
 `ls > 'file name with spaces'` which get the output of `ls` into a *single* file named `file name with spaces`

If coding in C++, you should use genuine C++ features. So you would read the line into a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) using [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). Then you should tokenize that string, i.e. transform it into a sequence of tokens. Some tokens are special (so `>` is not the same as the quoted `'>'` etc...). So define a `class Token` and implement a parser which gives a `std::vector<Token>` from a line (of type `std::string`) that you have previously read.

Of course you'll need to know some [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), so read e.g. [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). For instance, `cd` has to be a shell builtin which calls [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html). Redirections need to use [dup2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html) and [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html). Pipes need to use [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) etc....

BTW, you should look into the source code of [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) shells (and use `strace` to find out what they do). Most are coded in C (e.g. [GNU bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), or `sash`), but [fish](http://fishshell.com/) is coded in C++.

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to separate lexical symbols you should define lexical conventions. You can use flex++ to generate parser for you.

If you want to do redirection in your shell, try method dup2()
You can find [similar Q&A here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543443/in-c-how-do-you-redirect-stdin-stdout-stderr-to-files-when-making-an-execvp-or).