# Redirect command output to file in C

Tags: c

I am trying to redirect output of ls command to a file fout.txt
But file fout.txt contains only
Here is the output

Below is my program:

```
int fout, ferr;
char *tok[3];
tok[0] = "ls", tok[1] = ">", tok[2] = "fout.txt";
fout = open("fout.txt", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0600);
ferr = open("ferr.txt", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0600);
puts("Here is the output\n");
execvp(tok[0], tok);
close(fout);
close(ferr);
```

Please help here.

Comment: On what operating system are you running this?

Comment: Also, are you sure that you're using `puts` and not `fputs` with `fout`?

Comment: You don't check the return value of execvp(). Possibly failed due to file fout.txt being currently open by another process (your program).

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C how do you redirect stdin/stdout/stderr to files when making an execvp() or similar call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543443/in-c-how-do-you-redirect-stdin-stdout-stderr-to-files-when-making-an-execvp-or)

Comment: How could the file not be empty? You never write to it! But you should see at least `ls: >: No such file or directory` somewhere...

Comment: @SergeBallesta yes, I am getting the error ls: >: No such file or directory in file ferr.txt

Comment: @DanielJour here are my OS details: [user@cs-lb-66 ~]$ uname -a
Linux cs-lb-66.cse.iitkgp.ernet.in 2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.centos.plus.i686 #1 SMP Tue Dec 16 23:15:00 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
I am using puts and the string "Here is the output" along with file name (i.e. fout.txt) is getting written in file fout.txt

Answer (score 4):

Redirection such as you are attempting is not done directly via `execvp()` call.  It's done in `bash` [like this](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c#n4845):

```
/* Execute a simple command that is hopefully defined in a disk file
   somewhere.

   1) fork ()
   2) connect pipes
   3) look up the command
   4) do redirections
   5) execve ()
   6) If the execve failed, see if the file has executable mode set.
   If so, and it isn't a directory, then execute its contents as
   a shell script.

   Note that the filename hashing stuff has to take place up here,
   in the parent.  This is probably why the Bourne style shells
   don't handle it, since that would require them to go through
   this gnarly hair, for no good reason.
```

Note the "connect pipes".

(This is not meant to be a complete answer - the questioner should be required to research **something**...)

Answer (score 4):

The different redirections characters (`< > >> |`)are interpreted by the shells. As you ask a direct `execvp` execution, you just execute `ls` command with parameters `>` and `fout.txt`.

When I do that I get on stderr:

```
ls: >: No such file or directory
ls: fout.txt: No such file or directory
```

To redirect with the exec family of function you must explicitely open the files and use `dup2` to connect them to stdin (0), stdout(1) and/or stderr(2) as shown in [In C how do you redirect stdin/stdout/stderr to files when making an execvp() or similar call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543443)