# How to change stdout via program

Tags: c, linux, unix, stdout

Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
}
```

The above program print the output as "Hello world" in stdout(Terminal). But, I need the output of the program in some other 
file like "output.txt". So, is there any way to change the standard output of the process to some other file via programatically.

Comment: First up, it's `int main(void)` for the main function. And for the actual question, use the `>` redirection operator in your shell to redirect output.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543443/in-c-how-do-you-redirect-stdin-stdout-stderr-to-files-when-making-an-execvp-or

Comment: `fprintf()` is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [freopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/freopen.3.html) on `stdout` but it would close `stdout`.

You could use [dup2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html) like:

```
int newfd = open("/tmp/someoutput.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0640);
if (newfd<0) {
  perror("/tmp/someoutput.txt"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
if (dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, newfd)) {
  perror("dup2"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
```

But as commented by [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan) you really want to use redirections in your shell.

IMHO **redirecting `STDOUT_FILENO` like above smells *bad***.

A possible way might be to declare a global

```
FILE* myout = stdout;
```

and use always `fprintf(myout,` instead of `printf(` and perhaps sometimes doing `myout = fopen("/tmp/someoutput.txt");` with a test!

At least **inform the user that you are redirecting *his* `stdout`** (perhaps by some message to `stderr` etc...) !

Comment: I Experiment the following code. dup2 also not working.    #include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
void main()
{
 int fd=open("output.txt",O_CREAT,0655);
 dup2(1,fd);
 printf("Hello world\n");
}

Comment: You forgot to add the error testing. And I forgot the mode (3rd) argument to `open`, corrected that

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all this `stdout` changing business. Everything you have to do is to open a file and then write to it. Use [`fopen` and `fprintf`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm) to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`fprintf`](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCIQFjABahUKEwiR8pObjdHIAhXCH44KHdzqBMM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cplusplus.com%2Freference%2Fcstdio%2Ffprintf%2F&usg=AFQjCNFn1dBnOTtyMj4eM6RpRp14j0A0EQ&sig2=VGBsDtl2w8Ste_cdNTIiiw&bvm=bv.105454873,d.c2E) to write in a file .Open file in `w` or `a` mode and then use `fprintf` to write in it .