# Is it possible to send the message produced by perror() to /var/log/syslog?

Tags: c, error-handling, daemon, syslog, errno

I'm using perror() to print error messages, like:

```
pid = fork();
if (pid < 0) {
    perror("couldn't fork");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Is it possible to use `errno/perror()` facilities but direct the produced messages to the system log (`/var/log/syslog`)?

I ask this in the context of a program which can be run in both daemon and non-daemon modes. In daemon mode, `perror()` messages won't appear on syslog.

Comment: check early in the code as to the current mode.  Then write a small function that takes a string as a parameter and either calls perror() or calls syslog() depending on the current mode, as set earlier in the program

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `strerror` to get the error message based on an error code, without printing it. Then pass it to `syslog` like any other log message:

```
syslog(LOG_ERR, "Couldn't fork: %s", strerror(errno));
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the right permissions to write to syslog, I don't see why you couldn't pipe your output to that file. You could also use fprintf with stderr to output the error result to a file you create.

Comment: The requirements are that I'd like to use `errno` and `perror()` functionalities. `errno` is set to an appropriate error number when a system call fails and `perror()` prints the associated error message.

Comment: Unless he's running as root, he won't have permission to write directly to syslog. Everything should be sent through the `syslog()` function.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to redirect stderr (and possibly stdout) when you call your program.  For example: `./myprog 2>&1 | logger`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to this this the right way, i.e. using code specific to daemons (fork, etc.) and `syslog()`.

Comment: Using redirection, for example in a shell script or cron entry, *IS* the "right way" in the vast majority of circumstances.  If you want to log programmatically, then refer to "[man syslog](http://linux.die.net/man/3/syslog)".  And if you want to redirect (stderr, file #2), then use dup2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543443/in-c-how-do-you-redirect-stdin-stdout-stderr-to-files-when-making-an-execvp-or.  And if you want the error text independent of calling perror(), then [man strerror](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror).

Comment: I'm using `syslog()`. What I'd like to do is to conjugate `syslog()` with `errno/perror()`.

Comment: Then it sounds like strerror() might be your guy :)