# Redirecting file output of subprocess in C

Tags: c, io-redirection

I have either completely forgotten everything I thought to know about C, or something is going terribly wrong. I want to redirect the output of an subprocess (stdout and stderr) to a file. I do this this way:

```
if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
{
   get_host_date(today) ;
   int fd = open(log_filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND,
                 S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH) ;
   dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO) ;     // make stdout go to file
   dup2(fd, STDERR_FILENO) ;     // make stderr go to file
   fprintf(stderr, "This is a message") ;

   if ((status = execv(command, argv)) == -1)
   {
      printf("\n\nError: execve failed for %s", command) ;
      perror("\nexecve failure: ") ;         
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE) ;
   }
   close(STDOUT_FILENO) ;
   close(STDERR_FILENO) ;
}
```

The log file is created as specified, but the output does not go to the file. I made some test output (fprintf(stderr, "This is a message") ;), but this does not appear anywhere.
Wenn I checked the variable *fd*, I saw that it got the value of 1 (immediately after *open*). But should 1 not be the predefined output file descriptor?

Can anybody help me? I tried everything, but came to no result.

Thank you very much in beforehand
Best wishes
Jörg

P.S.: I'm working with RHEL and GNU-C.

Ok, here a comprimed code which does not work with me:

```
int main(int   argc,
         char* argv[])
{
   PROC_REC    proc ;

   strcpy(proc.command, "/home/islk/entw/v0816/exe/islk_server") ;
   strcpy(proc.args[0], "ISLK_DB1_SERV01") ;
   strcpy(proc.args[1], "") ;
   strcpy(proc.env[0], "ISLKSERVER_NR=5") ;
   strcpy(proc.env[1], "") ;

   ISLK_start_single_process(&proc) ;

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS) ;
}

static long ISLK_start_single_process(PROC_REC *prec_ptr)
{
   long     i=0 ;
   int      status ;
   char     *argv[16] ;
   char     command[256], log_filename[128], today[DB_DATE_DOM] ;
   pid_t    pid ;

   /* Set arguments */
   for (i=0; i<16; i++)
   {
      if (strcmp(prec_ptr->args[i], "") != 0)
         argv[i] = prec_ptr->args[i] ;
      else
         argv[i] = NULL ;
   }

   /*******************/
   /* Set environment */
   /*******************/
   for (i=0; i<16; i++)
   {
      if (strcmp(prec_ptr->env[i], "") != 0)
         putenv(prec_ptr->env[i]) ;
   }

   /*****************/
   /* Start process */
   /*****************/
   if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
   {
      get_host_date(today) ;
      bs_create_filename(log_filename, "islk$log", "", "%s_%8.8s.log",
                         prec_ptr->args[0], today) ;
      int fd = open(log_filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND,
                    S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH) ;
      int fdo = dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO) ;     // make stdout go to file
      int fde = dup2(fd, STDERR_FILENO) ;     // make stderr go to file
      close(fd) ;    
      fprintf(stdout, "This is a message") ;
      if ((status = execv(command, argv)) == -1)
      {
         printf("\n\nError: execv failed for %s", command) ;
         perror("\nexecv failure: ") ;         
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE) ;
      }
      close(STDOUT_FILENO) ;
      close(STDERR_FILENO) ;
   }
   else if (pid < 0)
   {
      printf("\n\nError: fork failed for %s", prec_ptr->args[0]) ;
      perror("\nfork failure: ") ;
      return ERROR ;
   }
   else
   {
      printf("\nProcess %d started for %s", pid, prec_ptr->args[0]) ;
      prec_ptr->pid = pid ;
   }

   return NO_ERROR ;
}
```

Tried the following:

```
dup2(fd, STDERR_FILENO) ;
dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO) ;
```

-> messages to stderr are written in file, to stdout not

```
dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO) ;
```

-> messages to stderr are written in terminal, to stdout nowhere

```
dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO) ;
dup2(STDERR_FILENO, STDOUT_FILENO) ;
```

-> messages to stderr are written in file, to stdout on terminal

```
dup2(fd, STDERR_FILENO) ;
dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, STDERR_FILENO) ;
```

-> messages to stderr are written in file, to stdout on terminal

-> Something seems to be a problem with stdout !

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Please provide a [mcve]. If I add the “obvious” bits to make your code compile cleanly, it behaves as expected.

Comment: Maybe use `fileno` to determine the integer descriptor. Also you should close fd after `dup2`. And I am unsure if you can use one file for both streams.

Comment: I think you're right with `fd == 1` being part of the problem. It seems that `stdout` has been closed before by your process or one of its parents and whatever happens there exactly could also prevent your redirection from working (e.g. `dup2(1, 1);` doesn't make sense, but I don't know if it would do harm)

Comment: off topic: the `close()` commands will never be executed. If `exec..()` succeeds it will never return and if it fails you're `exit()`ing before you would call `close()`

Comment: **always** check for errors. Please add the appropriate checks to *every* function, and report your findings (including errno)

Comment: Konstantin:
Tried it with only one redirection as well, does not work neither
Ingo:
I thought so as well because the process redirects its own output before (process is converted to a daemon with output to a file, which then starts subprocesses which should all have an separate logfile). But I simplified the program as shown above, and it does not work either.
Daniel: open returned 1, dup2 returned 1 and 2

Comment: @DanielJour: In the simplified program:

fd = open(...) -> returned fd=3
fdo = dup2(fd, 1) -> returned 1
fde = dup2(fd, 2) -> returned 2

Comment: Mhm ... is stdout perhaps marked as `FD_CLOEXEC` for what ever reason. Though that wouldn't explain why the `fprintf` before the `execv` isn't working. Can you try the approach listed in this answer (not the accepted one): http://stackoverflow.com/a/14543455/1116364

Comment: Also (don't know whether you saw my answer that i deleted in the mean time) ... even if it seems dumb .. could you exchange the arguments to `dup2` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have nearly answered the question by yourself by detecting that `fd == 1` "immediately after open()". According to [the dup2() man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html):

> The dup2() system call performs the same task as dup(), but instead
>          of using the lowest-numbered unused file descriptor, it uses the
>          descriptor number specified in newfd.  If the descriptor newfd was
>          previously open, it is silently closed before being reused.

So if `fd == 1` and you call `dup2( fd, STDOUT_FILENO );` then STDOUT_FILENO (which is 1 too) is closed and so is the descriptor to your redirection file. If you can't find out **why** stdout is closed in your program's environment maybe you could just do a test before calling `dup2()`:

```
if( fd != STDOUT_FILENO )
    dup2( fp, STDOUT_FILENO );
```

At least that should work as a trick to check if I'm right.

Comment: I found out why fd == 1 (closed stdout&stderr before). But I changed this (now fd == 3 after open). I am now so far that stderr is correctly written. But the messages to stdout just don't appear in the output file, even if I only redirect stdout (see above)

Comment: probably a dumb question, but are you sure that the`exec()`d command actually prints sth. to stdout? At least you should add a `fflush(stdout)` after `printf()` otherwise it will maybe just be buffered internally

Comment: :I made an fprintf(stdout, ...) and fprintf(stderr, ...) even before the exec(...). stderr came into the file, stdout not. Tomorrow I will try a fflush, perhaps it will help

Answer (score 0):

I now sinplified my program even more:

```
int main(int   argc,
         char* argv[])
{
   pid_t pid ;

   int fd = open("main.log", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND,
                 S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH) ;
   dup2(fd, STDERR_FILENO) ;     // make stdout go to file
   dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO) ;     // make stderr go to file      
   close(fd) ;
   fprintf(stdout, "Main: This is an output message") ;
   fprintf(stderr, "Main: This is an error message") ;
   fflush(stdout) ;
   fflush(stderr) ;

   if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
   {
      fd = open("sub.log", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND,
                    S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH) ;
      dup2(fd, STDERR_FILENO) ;     // make stdout go to file
      dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO) ;     // make stderr go to file      
      close(fd) ;    
      fprintf(stdout, "Sub: This is an output message") ;
      fprintf(stderr, "Sub: This is an error message") ;
      fflush(stdout) ;
      fflush(stderr) ;
      exit(0) ;
   }

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS) ;
}
```

which gives me

```
::::::::::::::
main.log
::::::::::::::
Main: This is an error messageMain: This is an output message
::::::::::::::
sub.log
::::::::::::::
Sub: This is an error messageSub: This is an output message
```

So, there must be something wrong in the called process. It makes output to stdout, but there must be something that hinders him from doing so when called as a subprocess (called interactively, there is lots of output on stdout).
If anybody has an idea what might be the reason, I would be thankful for any further help.
Thanks a lot for your help up to this point.

Jörg

Answer (score 0):

Eureka, I found it.

We call a library function from an external vendor. Before this call, everything works fine, after it, there is not output to *stdout* anymore.

I now contacted the vendor to ask what they do there. Meanwhile, this helps:

```
int saved_stdout = dup(STDOUT_FILENO) ;
// vendor library call
dup2(saved_stdout, STDOUT_FILENO) ;
```

Thanks to you all for your help

Best wishes, and a great weekend

Jörg