# Selection output file using dup()

Tags: c, io-redirection, dup

So I'm trying to redirect standard output to a file using dup().

```
int save_fd;
save_fd=dup(1); //saves the current stdout
close(1); //closes stdout
dup2(file.txt, 1);//redirect output to file.txt

//output goes to file.txt

dup2(save_fd, 1); restore stdout
close(1);
```

I know I can open a file using fopen. Since dup2 takes int, how do I specify the file descriptor for file.txt?

Comment: `fopen()` returns `FILE*` pointer but `open()` returns `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`open`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/open) which returns an fd instead of `fopen`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have two possibilities to get a file descriptor:

1. [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html)
2. [`fopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html) and then call [`fileno()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fileno.html) on the opened stream

So, in the case of `open()` the return value in case of success is the file descriptor you're looking for:

```
int fd = open("some_path", ...);
```

while in the case you want to use `fopen()`, you can still retrieve the file descriptor associated with the open stream but you need to call the function `fileno()`:

```
FILE *stream = fopen(some_file, "w");
int fd = fileno(stream);
```

Comment: Thanks @fedepad. I tried using open but get error saying, "invalid in C99" so I'm using open() for the time being. I used  `FILE *out=fopen("file.txt", "a"); fd_new=fileno(out);` and that worked. However now I don't get my terminal back after running. I did `fclose(out)` and I thought `dup2` restored it?

Comment: @user2217060 I gave you the general ways to get fd. Please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543443/in-c-how-do-you-redirect-stdin-stdout-stderr-to-files-when-making-an-execvp-or  which I think it's related to what you're trying to achieve.