# Strange issue redirecting output using dup2 sys call

Tags: c, unix, redirect

I'm having a strange issue using the dup2 system call to redirect STDOUT to a file.

I'm using 2 functions which i found here:
[In C how do you redirect stdin/stdout/stderr to files when making an execvp() or similar call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543443/in-c-how-do-you-redirect-stdin-stdout-stderr-to-files-when-making-an-execvp-or)

Below is a simple program i wrote to test the functions after i had errors.
The program works as expected and writes the input to the file.

```
int fd;
fpos_t pos;

int main(){
    while(1){
        char input[100];
        printf("Please enter text: ");
        gets(input);
        printf("\nString = %s\n", input);

        switchStdout("test.txt");

        puts("THIS TEXT SHOULD REDIRECT\n");
        printf("String(file) = %s\n", input);

        revertStdout();

        puts("This should come before the gets() ??\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

void switchStdout(const char *newStream)
{
  fflush(stdout);
  fgetpos(stdout, &pos);
  fd = dup(fileno(stdout));
  freopen(newStream, "w", stdout);
  return;
}

void revertStdout()
{
  fflush(stdout);
  dup2(fd, fileno(stdout));
  close(fd);
  clearerr(stdout);
  fsetpos(stdout, &pos);
}
```

After the revertStdout() function is called, the program appears to hang.

I realized that, in fact, the program has called gets() before printing "This should come before the gets() ??"

After I enter text, the program prints the skipped lines.

Here is the terminal output with what I enter in bold:

> Please enter text: **Hello!!!!**
>
> String = Hello!!!!
>
> **Why am i able to type here ??**
>   This should come before the gets() ??
>
> Please enter text:
>
> String = Why am i able to type here ??

Sorry about the long post. The program writes as expected to the file.

Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used

Comment: If you want to reopen a stream to use a different descriptor or handle, you might want `fdopen()`.  It’s not in the standard library, but Unix, Windows and OSX all support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, that's what happens when you sneak around behind the standard library's back.

Quoting `man setbuf`:

> Normally all files are block buffered.  When the first I/O operation occurs on a file, `malloc(3)` is called, and a buffer is obtained.  If a stream refers to a terminal (as `stdout` normally does) it  is  line buffered.

So, your `stdout` starts out referring to your terminal, and is line buffered. Then you `freopen` it to refer to a file, so (as part of reopening the stream), it becomes block-buffered. Then you `dup2` the fd, so now it is referring to the terminal again, but it is still the same stream; the standard library cannot known that you have reached into the guts of `stdout` and changed what it refers to. So it stays block-buffered, leading to the unexpected behaviour.

Changing buffering of a stream after the first output leads to undefined behaviour, although with some C library implementations it is possible if the buffer is empty (as it will be after the call to `fflush`). You should not count on this behaviour. You could, however, `freopen` the `stdout` stream again immediately after the `dup2`, passing a NULL first argument to `freopen`, thereby giving the standard library a chance to reinitialise.

For what it's worth, the `fflush` call in `switchStdout` is unnecessary since `freopen` effectively closes the stream. If you add the `freopen` to `revertStdout`, it will reset the error and end-of-file indicators, so you can remove the call to `clearerr`.

Comment: Adding freopen(NULL, "w", stdout) after dup2 fixed it. Thanks!